# IE displays table row border at times

Tags: html, css, materialize

In in IE 11 the table row is displaying a white line border even though it has `border: none;` This problem doesn't occur on firefox and chrome.

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Shank09/nv6vxeqa/5/)

**Image in IE:**

[image]

**Image in Chrome**

[image]

After playing around with the code, I saw that the rounded corners cause this issue.

```
table.striped > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
table.striped > tbody > tr > td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **IE** can not take "**border**" when you use a "**border_radius**". With this "CSS", this issue is solved in the "**IE**"

```
table.striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) > td
{
  border-left: solid 1em #F2F2F2!important;
}

table.striped > tbody > tr > td.failed
{
  border-left: solid 1em #FF4359!important;
}

table.striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(even) > td,
table.striped > tbody > tr > td:first-child
{
  border-left: none!important;
}
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
.searchbox {
  width: 0% !important;
}
.searchbox.open {
  width:45% !important;
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}
.searchicon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.failed {
    background-color: #ff4359;
    color: white;
}
.pad-l-15 {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

body {
  background-color: #F3F3F2;
}

table.striped > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

table.striped > tbody > tr > td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

#listcount {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #727d93;
}

.icons {
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.card .card-content .card-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
    table.striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) > td
    {
      border-left: solid 1em #F2F2F2!important;
    }
    table.striped > tbody > tr > td.failed
    {
      border-left: solid 1em #FF4359!important;
    }
      table.striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(even) > td,
      table.striped > tbody > tr > td:first-child
    {
      border-left: none!important;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title">
              <i class="material-icons">business_center</i>
                My List
              <span id="listcount">
                (12)
              </span>
              <div class="icons">
                 
                <span class="new badge yellow" data-badge-caption="">
                  1
                </span>
                
              </div>
              <input id="fund-search" type="search" class="searchbox" placeholder="Search">
                    <i class="material-icons right searchicon" ng-click="toggleSearch()">search</i>
               
            </span>
            
            <div class="">
               <table class="table striped table-hover table-curved" ng-controller="Hello">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="pad-l-15"><b>12345</b></td>
                        <td>Random Text @</td>
                        <td><b>300121</b></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="failed pad-l-15"><b>12345678</b></td>
                        <td class="failed">Random Text @</td>
                        <td class="failed"><b>300121</b></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="pad-l-15"><b>123</b></td>
                        <td>Random Text @</td>
                        <td><b>300121</b></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="pad-l-15"><b>123</b></td>
                        <td>Random Text @</td>
                        <td><b>300121</b></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="pad-l-15"><b>123</b></td>
                        <td>Random Text @</td>
                        <td><b>300121</b></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="pad-l-15"><b>123</b></td>
                        <td>Random Text @</td>
                        <td><b>300121</b></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col s12 m6">
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title">My Right List
            <span class="new badge red" data-badge-caption="">4</span>
            </span>
            <div class="table-responsive">
               <table class="table striped table-hover table-curved" ng-controller="Hello">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td><b>12345</b></td>
                        <td>Random Text @</td>
                        <td><b>300121</b></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><b>12345678</b></td>
                        <td>Random Text @</td>
                        <td><b>300121</b></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col s12 m6">
            <div class="card">
               <div class="card-content">
                  <span class="card-title">Nested left</span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col s12 m6">
            <div class="card">
               <div class="card-content">
                  <span class="card-title">Nested right</span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you expand the page, the lines comes back

Comment: Increase the pixel value to 2. There is always a problem with Internet Explorer :(

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help much, I still can see the white line. :/ hate IE

Comment: Interestingly, there is no problem with my IE. please wait i find solution

Comment: Is there a way to mimic this table with using divs? will that resolve some issues?

Comment: I changed the code and use the "em" instead of the "px".please try

Comment: Yes, this fixes it in IE. But it created an issue on chrome & firefox. The left corner is not rounded anymore

Comment: Change the size of the "em" and "padding <td>" to get the desired view

Comment: I am the enemy of Internet Explorer. Good luck :))